# Objective-C How to write regex from character until matches first *

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

```
\r\nThis PM was sent by [ helloworld ] helloworld@gmail.com,\r\nMembership Status : Non-Verified Member\r\nhttp://www.gg.com/A/F/U.asp?UserID=helloworld@1\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nHi, may i know does the item still available?\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n  *** This email was sent using www.gg.com***

NSString *regexStr = @"@1(.*?)[\\*]";
NSError *error;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regexStr options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:message options:NSMatchingReportCompletion range:NSMakeRange(0, [message length])];

if ([matches count] > 0) {
    for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
        NSString* matchText = [message substringWithRange:[match range]];
        NSLog(@"match: %@", matchText);
        NSRange group1 = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
        NSLog(@"group1: %@", [message substringWithRange:group1]);
    }
}
```

I wish to obtain "Hi, may i know does the item still available?" from the string above in Objective-C

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

`NSString *regexStr = @"@1(.*?)\\*";`

Also use the `NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators` option.